# Where to start from to develop for tablets (ICS)?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am familiar with android 2.2 and I have been developing for phones, now where to start from when developing for ICS tablets. The major thing I learned from quick-google that now I will have to use fragments for multi-pane layouts rather than mere Activity. What else do I need to look for before starting? 
Some links would be helpful (for fragments too).

Comment: [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_overview) is a nice tutorial on using fragments

Comment: Thanks, mate. Vogella is a lifesaver.

Comment: Fragments are tricky creatures if you're used to 2.2. Have a good read through how they work and, my suggestion is that you write a practice app to get to know their subtleties before you jump into an app you plan on releasing.

Comment: just fragment is not enough for tablet ..you have to learn layout-xhdpi, values folder version and more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is how you can set up your Emulator to act as a tablet.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_tablet_virtual-device-configuration/)

[Here is a great guide on supporting tablets and handsets.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

[And lastly a very useful guide for fragments](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about making UI's look good for different screen sizes, look into size specific drawables and resources, also making use of the screen. Look under training in developing on d.android.com